# Is the "sdetable" command available with ArcGIS Workgroup

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, sql-server, versioning

Is the "sdetable" command available with ArcGIS Workgroup, or only the Enterprise edition?

We have ArcGIS Server Workgroup 9.3.1 and want to update some of the feature class tables with data from another system using SQL UPDATE commands.  From taking a look at the documentation, we must first create a multi-versioned view, and then run the SQL UPDATE commands against this view.  The problem is that we do not have the "sdetable" command required to create the multi-versioned view.  We think that these command line tools may be available only in the Enterprise edition.

Is there another way that we can perform basic data updates with SQL commands in the Workgroup Edition?  I understand that the correct way to do this is not by editing the default version directly.

EDIT:
Our data is versioned for different uses, including some field applications.  We were planning on creating a "sql-updates" version just for making updates to attributes in a feature class.  If I use SQL UPDATE commands to update this version, my concern is that the changes will not get replicated to the other versions, or the data could become corrupt.  This seems like it would be bypassing delta table entries.

From what I have read, we should use "sdetable" to create a multiversioned view, and then use stored procedures create_version, set_current_version, edit_version (1 - start session),  run my updates, edit_version (2 - close session), and finally delete_version (after reconciled).  I see these stored procedures in the database, but can't do the first step of creating the multiversioned view.  Maybe it would be possible to perform these steps on the "sql-updates" version without creating the view.

**EDIT 2:**
Since the original question has been answered, I opened a new question:
[How can we use SQL to update feature class attributes in a versioned geodatabase in ArcGIS Workgroup](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8626/how-can-we-use-sql-to-update-feature-class-attributes-in-a-versioned-geodatabase)

Comment: I think i fully see your issue for the first time. You mentioned part of a network. Do you mean it has network objects in it? If so, you are probably right. You need to only utilize esri tools or you will have sde table  and metadata problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are correct. The commands you need are in the enterprise edition.
[See this link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/Support_files/admincmdref.htm) for ver 10 but still applies to 9.3.1 I beleive.

That said you might try or read about the GDBT for 9.3x.
 I don't remember if it had tools to create views but I do remember having some tools for version management.
[GDBT tool set](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/gdbt/system-requirements.html).

[image: Geodatabase toolset]

Comment: Sounds like an interesting tool set, even though they say it is not supported.  If I use this, would I have to write some .Net code to perform the database updates?  It seems like there should be an easier way to do attribute updates from SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not versioned, you should be able to update it simply by editing it in the base tables using SQL.  I've done it numerous times with SDE Workgroup without any difficulties.

Comment: It's versioned, I updated the question with this information.  It's also part of a network.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is **no**. ArcGIS Workgroup edition does not run in the ArcSDE Worker Process; or provide to you the whole toolkit needs to have the sdetable or sdelayer tools or even the full API.

ArcGIS/ArcSDE Workgroup live in the Direct-Connect world where SQL is all driven from the ArcGIS application, less from the service level.